# transfer vtk video stream to ros image

Tags: image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I use python and vtk to integrate diagrams and AR-stuff into video streams. It works fine, I get a augmented video on my screen. Now I want to transfer this output into a stream of ROS image messages, but I did not find a suitable solution.

For an illustration I adapted a vtk standard example for animations, a moving spere. How to publish the current image during a timer callback?

Best wishes from Germany

Poseidonius

```
import vtk

class vtkTimerCallback():
   def __init__(self):
       self.timer_count = 0
       #self.pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', image)
       #rospy.init_node('videosource')


   def execute(self,obj,event):
       print self.timer_count
       self.actor.SetPosition(self.timer_count, self.timer_count,0);
       iren = obj
       iren.GetRenderWindow().Render()
       self.timer_count += 1
       if self.timer_count > 10:
       self.timer_count = -10
       # here I want to do something like 
       # self.pub(?)

 def main():
 #Create a sphere
     sphereSource = vtk.vtkSphereSource()
     sphereSource.SetCenter(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
     sphereSource.SetRadius(5)

 #Create a mapper and actor
     mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
     mapper.SetInputConnection(sphereSource.GetOutputPort())
     actor = vtk.vtkActor()
     actor.SetMapper(mapper)
     prop = actor.GetProperty()

 # Setup a renderer, render window, and interactor
    renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow() 
    renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer);
    renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

 #Add the actor to the scene
    renderer.AddActor(actor)
    renderer.SetBackground(1,1,1) # Background color white

 #Render and interact
    renderWindow.Render()

 # Initialize must be called prior to creating timer events.
    renderWindowInteractor.Initialize()

 # Sign up to receive TimerEvent
    cb = vtkTimerCallback()
    cb.actor = actor
    renderWindowInteractor.AddObserver('TimerEvent', cb.execute)
    timerId = renderWindowInteractor.CreateRepeatingTimer(100);

 # start the interaction and timer
    renderWindowInteractor.Start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12404/transfer-vtk-video-stream-to-ros-image/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2011-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure of any ROS method to convert the VTK datatypes to ROS images. You might have to make a converter for yourself. I'd take a look [here](http://www.vtk.org/VTK/img/file-formats.pdf) to figure out the datatypes in VTK streams. [Here](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) is the ROS datatype for images.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0